# Google drive API, how to use a one-stop authentication on server?

Tags: php, web-applications, google-drive-api

I want to make a PHP app that allows my users to collaborate their document in group on Google Drive. With Google Drive API, instead of asking all my users to use their own google account, can I use a google account on server and all user can view/edit the docs at the same time? Please advise me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible using google docs. You could implement your own realtime solution with realtime api which will be a lot or work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there an alternative way to do that ? If we do it manually with google docs, we can copy a link and send it to anyone and they can work with it. We have tried it but we didn't manage to get the same link programmatically.